# Is there any way to fold/collapse regional code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-folding

I used this way to get code folding in Netbeans:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" description">
....
// </editor-fold>
```

and Visual Studio:

```
#region description
...
#endregion
```

but I can't find the same usage in eclipse.
How can I use code folding in Eclipse?

Comment: @Ajeet: This question was 2 years ago past. But, pls read my question and question in link you had provided carefully. They are different questions.

Comment: There used to be a plug-in called Coffee-Bytes for this -- but it doesn't seem to exist anymore, if it does I doubt it's compatible with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: the Coffee-Bytes plugin is mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8158721/3380951)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Eclipse supports code folding.

Go to workbench preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors, and check the "Enable folding" box.

Then go to workbench preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding, and adjust your folding preferences.

Comment: But, I still can't use code folding for a block of code (codes not in comment out block and parentheses block).

Comment: As far as I know, such fine-level folding isn't available with Eclipse, at least not with Eclipse Juno (which is the version that I am using). A quick search in Eclipse's BugZilla database shows many feature requests related to folding with the Java editor, some of them date years back.

Comment: Thanks Isaac. Your answer helped me so much.

Comment: Technically speaking this answer is misleading, as Eclipse doesn't seem to support the code folding sought by OP.

Comment: Also, you could check the keys (Ctrl + Shift + NUM_PAD_DIVIDE) in Preferences -> General -> Keys.

Comment: useful answer ty

Answer (score 6):

Windows->Preferences->(C/C++)->Editors->Folding

(C/C++) will change based on the language you are using. Generally each language plugin will have its own folding options

Answer (score 5):

The `<editor-fold` and `#region` can be used as a block folding wrapping anything you want, including not just a function or a comment but both or even multiples functions, comments, variables, etc.

Eclipse does not has such functionality. 
I am using Eclipse Neon and still missing this.

Comment: 2023, still true, I'm using STM32CubeIDE and C++, I have `#pragma region` / `#pragma endregion` that is weirdly supported in `Outline` view, but not supported by the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I created a fork and an update site for the old [coffee bytes code folding plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coffeeby1/) that works with Eclipse Neon:
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site

Comment: Works like a charm in Eclipse 4.7.3a, Oxygen.3a! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I'd like to add some input.

Eclipse doesn't natively support custom code folding blocks, as does Visual Studio with its `#region` and `#endregion` directives, or Netbeans with its `//<editor-fold defaulstate="collapsed" desc="My custom code folding block"` and `//</editor-fold>`.

(IntelliJ supports this as well, with both aforementioned methods working, depending on how the IDE is configured.)

---

If you happen to be working in Eclipse with the CDT (as in C/C++), there is a way around.
I've tried installing the plugins mentioned, but they either do not exist anymore, or the installation makes the IDE unstable.

Create a header file in a central location, which contains macros, etc (optional).
In that header, simply define a FOLD macro, as below:

```
#define FOLD //
```

Each file that #includes your central header file will also have a reference to the macro above.

An example use of this would be:

```
#ifdef FOLD Struct MyFileStruct
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct MyFileStruct {
        WCHAR fileName[FILENAMELEN];  // File name
        WCHAR fileInfos[32];          // File info
        WCHAR fileDate[32];           // File date
        DWORD sizeInBytes;            // File size
} File;
#pragma pack()
#endif
```

---

If the way this works is unclear, I suggest looking in to the [C Preprocessor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm)

I hope this is of some use!

Comment: There's even simpler way: `#if 1 // My region name` and `#endif` at the end. It's even shorter than any original "region" tags ;) Works nicely with CDT / STM32CubeIDE.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [SimonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54146078/8060547) and Harry (for the comment) for this tip:

In C/C++ (Eclipse CDT or STM32CubeIDE), you can use conditional compilation for a simple way to fold code blocks:

```
#if 1 // My region name
// Code you want to fold
#endif
```

Wrap the code you want to fold with #if 1 and #endif. This conditionally includes the code, effectively folding it until you remove the #if 1.