# How to Create a Region in eclipse like Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, m2eclipse

I am working with Eclipse tool and I am so curious to know about that how can I create `Region` in Eclipse like in `Visual Studio` we can create :

```
#region abc

// Some Code 

#endregion abc
```

How to achieve the same thing in Eclipse.

Comment: What behaviour do you want to imitate? What does #region do?

Comment: #region just collapses the data written between # region and #endregion. so it is useful if you want to hide some unused code or used code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code folding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505413/code-folding-in-eclipse)

Comment: There is no such method in Eclipse and Intelliji IDE as well. I was from Visual Studio I miss this feature. I think this question possible duplicate of.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Got to long for a comment ..

There is code folding in Eclipse. You can find it in Window-> Preferences, then search for "folding". But it just wraps methods/functions/comments etc.

There is a plugin that used to work in Eclipse 4.2 named [Coffee Bytes](https://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/), but it is no longer maintained. So usage is at your own risk.

Lots of "buts", I know ;).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not have something like Visual Studio's region. but you can use the below code and enable folding for this purpose.

```
#if (1) //myregion
C++ code here
#endif //end myregion
```

You can add a new template like the below in the **Prefrences > C/C++ > Templates** menu to add it to *surround with* and *code snippet*(auto-complete with CTRL+Space)

```
#if(1) /* region: ${name} */

${line_selection}${cursor}

#endif   /* region end: ${name} */
```

Answer (score 0):

`#region` is a feature of the C# language. Unless you are writing C# in Eclipse through some plugin (and there is one actually), you can't. If you are writing C# in Eclipse, then just type it. But I don't know if Eclipse will collapse it like Visual Studio does.

Comment: Note, it's not really a feature of C#, but of the Visual Studio as an IDE. For instance, you can use #region in Java/JavaScript if you're using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-regions

Answer (score 0):

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp) 
There is no way to do this in eclipse.The eclipse ide does not provide a 
way to region off areas of code like visual studio does I came from visual 
studio to eclipse and this is a problem I had.