# How to fold code block in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

All:

I wonder how to collapse a block(not just by class method level but also like if while switch level) of code in eclipse(mine is Indigo).

Thanks

Comment: possible already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505413/code-folding-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Eclipse does not support folding on the kind of scale that you're talking about (ifs, whiles, switches) natively. However, there are all sorts of plugins that you can look into. One such plugin can be found  [here](http://kosiara87.blogspot.de/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html). This particular plugin was designed for Indigo as well.