# How can I get custom code-folding in eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, text-editor, code-folding

I would organize my code much better if I could collapse sections or regions of it at my disposal, regardless of whether they are a block or not.

However, I can't find a way to do it in eclipse. I have seen that there is a plugin called coffee-bytes, but it doesn't seem to work with the most recent versions of eclipse.

I can't be the only person with this problem right?, in c++ you can split code using #region, and many other editors also support custom-folding, so I know it's a used function. Can anyone tell me how can I use this function in eclipse?

I searched for plugins in the marketplace as well, but it isnt clear to me if any of those plugins would help for my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to fold/collapse regional code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505413/is-there-any-way-to-fold-collapse-regional-code-in-eclipse)