# Are there any code folding plugins for Eclipse 2018-12?

Tags: eclipse-2018-12

I have been looking for a while now for code folding plugins, but none of them are for Eclipse 2018-12 version. Does anyone know of any that will work with THIS version? I know that I will probably be gotten on to for posting a question like this, but this seems like the place to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, But you can check and let us know.

[Eclipse Folding](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding)

You can see the installation guide. See the accepted answer.
Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872921/code-folding-plugin-for-eclipse).

Comment: Do you simply drag and drop into the plugins folder of eclipse?