# Code folding in Notepad++ for PHP

Tags: php, notepad++, code-folding

I'm using Notepad++ 6.6.9. In Java I'm able to use code folding as simple as this:

```
//{ region 1
    public Core(){}
//}
```

I don't even need to save. Just add this sort of code and collapsable itens are added around it.

But in PHP I can't make it work. I've tried the following:

```
//{#region LOADING
//{START LOADING
//{ region 1

//}
//}END example
//}#endregion LOADING
```

It simply doesn't work. Could somebody point me any working code, or a tutorial on how to configuring some custom one?

Comment: Do you mean this thing? http://screencloud.net/v/pdQH

Comment: Yes, but I want custom folding. I wanna add it wherever I need, not only inside functions, ifs, loops, etc.

Answer (score 4):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954860/3869072

I just looked for the same, so you can simply write this:

```
#region LOADING
//Your code here
#endregion LOADING
```

the # works obviously as a comment in php